# Statistical test for Likert scale perceptions of application of a HR development model to dental restorative specialty training

Tags: nonparametric, ordinal-data, likert

I'd be most grateful for some advice about suitable statistical testing for a research project.

It's a survey questionnaire to restorative specialty trainees and alumni trainees exploring the application of a HR management model to specialty training in a University teaching hospital. Essentially the model brings together generalist and specialist organisational/individual principles in the most effective combinations and I'm proposing that a university hospital training centre does indeed follow the principles.

There will be general demographics before exploring 5 point Likert scale ordinal agreement (non parametric strongly disagree to strongly agree) with statements about relation of the HR model principles to training at the Eastman. I can present the data with stacked bar charts with additional mean s for the different groups (current trainees, alumni trainees, trainees before/after covid) but am wondering about how best to set a threshold to prove from the responses that the HR model does indeed apply and how to present this?

Thanks very much in advance and any further questions please let me know.